# What transformations can be performed in MDX?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm new to MDX. I understand that MDX is a query language, not a data transformation language. However, I'm also aware that this distinction is partially meaningless; there is no clear line between transformation and reporting, and every query language is capable of some transformation. Proficiency in a query language requires knowing what transformations are reasonable, and which require a redesign of the underlying schema.

From what I've seen of MDX, it clearly has features designed for creating calculated members within a dimension. Beyond that, however, I'm not clear on its transformation capabilities. Can anyone provide a concise summary of which types of transformations MDX can reasonably be expected to do?

I don't intend for this question to be limited to my particular reporting challenge. However, by describing my project, I can illustrate a few of the transformation types I'm interested in. So, here's a description of what I'm working on:

I need to use MDX to create some inventory and sales reports. I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services. The data is organized into three different cubes: On-Hand Inventory, In-Transit Inventory, and Sales. My reports require that the data be transformed in several ways. For instance:

1) I need to infer a "Months" attribute from the "Weeks" attribute, using the rules of a 4-4-5 calendar. I'm fairly certain this can be done elegantly with MDX.

2) I need to infer a "Calendar Month" dimension from the "Months" attribute. I believe this can be done with MDX, but I'm not sure whether there is an elegant solution or a kludge which should be avoided in favor of a schema redesign.

3) I need to infer a "Region" dimension from the "Warehouse" dimension. I've seen no evidence that this can be done in an elegant way by MDX.

4) I need to calculate total inventory as On-Hand Inventory plus In-Transit Inventory. From searching the web, it seems that querying two different cubes is possible, but is discouraged in favor of schema redesign, but the water is still very muddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say most of your requirements can be done with Analysis Services, but not necessarily with MDX. Rather, they would be done in cube design. This is normally done using the GUI, which is Visual Studio called BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio). If you absolutely want to use a language, you could use XMLA, which is how BIDS communicates with the Analysis Services server. But this would still not be MDX, and is not very well documented, and hence difficult to learn. You could use .net and AMO, but the easiest way is the GUI in BIDS.

And some of your requirements would optimally be implemented in the design of the relational tables on which the cubes are based. The first three of your requirements are best implemented in the dimension tables, and then just used in the dimension objects in the cube definition. For the fourth requirement, you are right, this can easily be implemented in a calculated measure in the cube calculation script. And this, indeed, is MDX.

In theory, you could also implement the first three requirements somehow in MDX. But this would be complex, difficult to maintain and have bad performance. MDX is just not designed for tis type of requirement.